# How to make a PHP SOAP client and store the result xml in php variables

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am using PHP and have never used SOAP and PHP before.

I need to build **a Soap PHP Client** which is calling and retrieves information from a 
 **Soap server .NET Web service**.

I'm currently working on getting information for **Doctors in Dutch Health care system**
.for Every doctor which is registered in the Dutch of health care system you can retrieve 
his information through his unique **unique BIG ID - 11 digit unique number** ) from a **SOAP web-service using WSDL**.

So when I am calling the **SOAP server** :
(link of the server is below)

into this a Testing web site (like soapclinet.com)

my **XML response is correct and looks exactly like this XML below**
in brackets the information of the doctor that i want to capture in php.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
 <ListHcpApprox3Result xmlns="http://services.cibg.nl/ExternalUser">
  <ListHcpApprox>
   <ListHcpApprox3>
    <HcpNumber>200822</HcpNumber>
    <BirthSurname> [Surname of the Doctor]</BirthSurname>
    <MailingName> [Mailing name of the doctor] </MailingName>
    <Initial> [Initials of the doctor] </Initial>
    <Gender> [Gender of the doctor] </Gender>
    <ArticleRegistration>
    <ArticleRegistrationExtApp>
    <ArticleRegistrationNumber> [unique BIG ID]  </ArticleRegistrationNumber>
    <StartDate>1998-12-10T00:00:00</StartDate>
    <EndDate xsi:nil="true"/>
    <TypeOfSpecialismId>15</TypeOfSpecialismId>
    </SpecialismExtApp>
    </Specialism>
    <Mention/>
    <JudgmentProvision/>
    <Limitation/>
   </ListHcpApprox3>
  </ListHcpApprox>
 </ListHcpApprox3Result>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

***I need to build a PHP web page which will do exactly the same SOAP call.***

**the address of the wsdl file is this:**

webservices.cibg.nl/Ribiz/OpenbaarV2.asmx?wsdl.asmx?wsdl

**The soap server address is this:**
http://webservices-acc.cibg.nl/Ribiz/OpenbaarV2.asmx

**The soap action is this:**
http://services.cibg.nl/ExternalUser/ListHcpApprox3

***and the SOAP message that i sent is this:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
 <listHcpApproxRequest xmlns="http://services.cibg.nl/ExternalUser">
  <WebSite>Ribiz</WebSite>
  <RegistrationNumber> [BIG ID number of the doctor] </RegistrationNumber>
 </listHcpApproxRequest>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

(in brackets is the BIG ID number of the doctor that we send in SOAP server)

**How can I write the above SOAP action into PHP code and store in PHP the variables of the XML that i get as response ?**

the variables in XML response that I need to store in php code are these...

```
<HcpNumber>200822</HcpNumber>
<BirthSurname> [Surname of the Doctor]</BirthSurname>
<MailingName> [Mailing name of the doctor] </MailingName>
<Initial> [Initials of the doctor] </Initial>
<Gender> [Gender of the doctor] </Gender>
```

**Update1:** *This is the output of the var_dump. Where xxxxxxx are the values that I want to store in php variables!*

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'ListHcpApprox' => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'ListHcpApprox3' => 
        object(stdClass)[4]
          public 'HcpNumber' => string 'xxxxxxxxx' (length=6)
          public 'BirthSurname' => string 'xxxxxxxxxxx' (length=9)
          public 'MailingName' => string 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' (length=18)
          public 'Initial' => string 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' (length=8)
          public 'Gender' => string 'x' (length=1)
          public 'ArticleRegistration' => 
            object(stdClass)[5]
              ...
          public 'Specialism' => 
            object(stdClass)[7]
              ...
          public 'Mention' => 
            object(stdClass)[9]
              ...
          public 'JudgmentProvision' => 
            object(stdClass)[10]
              ...
          public 'Limitation' => 
            object(stdClass)[11]
              ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP has a native [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) class that makes it easy to call SOAP services. It provides a simple interface allowing you to use native PHP arrays and objects for the request and response data, and handles the intricacies of the SOAP envelope and WSDL.

```
// create a new SoapClient and pass it the WSDL
$client = new SoapClient('http://webservices.cibg.nl/Ribiz/OpenbaarV2.asmx?WSDL');

// define the input parameters for the webservice call
$params = array('WebSite' => 'Ribiz', 'RegistrationNumber' => 'xxxxxxxxxx');
// invoke the ListHcpApprox3 method
$response = $client->ListHcpApprox3($params);

// print out the response to see its structure
var_dump($response);
```

You can pick the variables out of the response like this:

```
$data = $response->ListHcpApprox->ListHcpApprox3
$HcpNumber = $data->HcpNumber;
$BirthSurname = $data->BirthSurname;

echo $HcpNumber;
```

Comment: It worked! But I get the results as plein text. Can I add something in the code which will assign me the var_dump($response) into several php variables???

Comment: Yes var_dump outputs the object as text for debugging, so you can see the structure. Update the question with the var_dump output, then I can tell you how to get the variables.

Comment: I have just update the question! Thanks for any further help!

Comment: See my edit - added example of accessing the HcpNumber and BirthSurname, the other variables can be accessed in the same way.

Comment: Thank you MrCode! Is there a way to credit you for your correct answers??? I am new in Stack Overflow eventhough I read it for a long time