# .NET web service and php client

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am new to php client interaction with .NET web service. I have looked around and aware of posts like the one below but there are not the answer to my question.

[How to make a PHP SOAP client and store the result xml in php variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567424/how-to-make-a-php-soap-client-and-store-the-result-xml-in-php-variables)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php

[Consume a .Net web service using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062323/consume-a-net-web-service-using-php)

A PHP SOAP client (to request and get response) is needed for .NET web service 
(http://localhost:8080/someexample/myservice.wsdl). The input/request would look like this:

```
<input>
    <the_input name="secondyear">
      <authen>
        <Teacher>
         <teacherid>MrX</teacherid> 
         <password>t_pass</password> 
        </Teacher>
        <Student>
         <studentid>kids</studentid> 
         <password>s_pass</password> 
        </Student>
       </authen>
     <parameters>
        <parameter name="maths" value="123" /> 
        <parameter name="physics" value="abc" />
        <parameter name="sports" value="def" /> 
     </parameters>
    </the_input>
</input>
```

Here is what i got but not working and i am not sure i am on the right track:

```
<?php 
 require_once("lib/nusoap.php");
 $url="http://example.com/someexample/myservice.wsdl";
 $client = new SoapClient($url);

 $teacherid='MrX';
 $tpassword='t_pass';
 $studentid='kids';
 $spassword='s_pass';
 $ns = "http://example.com/";

 //Body of the Soap Header.
 $headerbody = array ('Teacher' => array('teacherid' => $teacherid,
                                      'password' => $tpassword ),
                      'Student' => array('stendentid' => $studentid,
                                       'password' => $spassword ));
 //Create Soap Header.
 $header = new SOAPHeader($ns, 'Authen', $headerbody);

 //set the Headers of Soap Client.
 $headerparam=$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

 $name ='secondyear';
 $service_name = array('the_input'=>$name);

 $result =$client->__SoapCall($service_name,$headerparam)
 print_r ($result);
?>
```

I read somewhere in order to authenticate to a web service, one should put authentication parameter in php header, so what goes to the php body then or is it needed? is it the parameters? The parameter has the format of name and value, how do i do that in php array? is any relevant example available? as mentioned i've done my research and not clear how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I figured out myself and I post the answer here, in case it helps someone has the same problem.
I just create a xml varible:

```
$myxml ='<the_input name="secondyear">
  <authen>
    <Teacher>
     <teacherid>MrX</teacherid> 
     <password>t_pass</password> 
    </Teacher>
    <Student>
     <studentid>kids</studentid> 
     <password>s_pass</password> 
    </Student>
   </authen>
 <parameters>
    <parameter name="maths" value="123" /> 
    <parameter name="physics" value="abc" />
    <parameter name="sports" value="def" /> 
 </parameters>
</the_input>'
```

then called it as a parameter (in the soap call function):

```
<?php
 require_once("lib/nusoap.php");
 $url="http://example.com/someexample/myservice.wsdl";
 $client = new SoapClient($url);

 $result =$client->input(array(the_input=>$myxml));
 print_r ($result);
?>
```

Vola, got connected to web service.
When problem gets solved, it looks very easy.